# How to Display the XML data to a GRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, datatable, linq-to-xml

i have this following XML file

```
<personaldetails>
<name>ravi</name>
<id>1</id>
<branch>CSE</branch>
</personaldetails>
<professionaldetails>
<name>ravi</name>
<age>25</age>
<gender>male</gender>
 </professionaldetails>
```

This is the sample data .so,now when i search with a name **"ravi"** in textbox it should display both tables i.e; personal and professional.how to do this using DATATABLE  and bind it to  GRIDVIEW.
Am doing this in ASP.NET using **C#** 
How can we solve this issue using **c#**
**or**
can we  do this using **LINQ QUERIES**

Answer (score 0):

You might use Linq To XML with a valid XML. ie:

```
string sXML = @"<root>
<personaldetails>
<name>ravi</name>
<id>1</id>
<branch>CSE</branch>
</personaldetails>
<professionaldetails>
<name>ravi</name>
<age>25</age>
<gender>male</gender>
</professionaldetails>
</root>";

var prd = XElement
    .Parse(sXML)
    .Descendants()
    .Where(xe => xe.Name=="professionaldetails" && (string)xe.Element("name") == "ravi")
    .Select(p => new {
        Name = (string)p.Element("name"),
        Age = (int?)p.Element("age"),
        Gender = (string)p.Element("gender")
    })  ;
```